# elastic search multiple indexes bulk import

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I am trying to import data from multiple .xlsx files containing multiple worksheets to elastic search.  My process is like this:

1. I open the xlsx file and create a list of all the worksheets
2. I create a pandas dataframe for each worksheet and convert it to json
3. I import the json to elastic using helpers.bulk method.
   My problem is that when I run it I get the error:

> RequestError: RequestError(400, 'action_request_validation_exception', 'Validation Failed: 1: index is missing;2: type is missing;

Can Anyone point to an example with loop through multiple files and multiple worksheets?

Comment: You have to give a type when you are indexing in bulk

Comment: when I tried to import in bulk using helpers the syntax was 
```result = helpers.bulk(es, create_json(file,sheets,dfs), chunk_size=1000)```. According to helpers documentation there isn't somewhere wher I can define the index name or the type

Answer (score 0):

What `helpers.bulk` expect as second parameter is an array of actions that should look like this:

```
{
    '_index': 'index-name',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': 42,
    '_source': {
        "title": "Hello World!",
        "body": "..."
    }
}
```

You need:

- `_index`: the index name where to index the document
- `_type`: must be `_doc` (this is going to disappear as of version 8)
- `_id`: the ID of the document
- `_source`: the actual content of the document you want to index.

Make sure to check that your `create_json` function is adding all those parameters.

**UPDATE:**

Looking at your code...

Why do you call `list_of_json()` and `get_data_from_file()` twice? Only the second call is needed

```
list_of_json()
json_names = list_of_json()
...
get_data_from_file(json_names)
data = get_data_from_file(json_names)
```

Then in `bulk_json_data` you need to change the line I highlighted

```
def bulk_json_data(json_names):
    for m in json_names:
        for doc in m:
            actions = [
                {'_index': doc,
                 '_type': '_doc',      <--- change this line
                 '_id':uuid.uuid4(),
                 '_source': data}
            ]

    return actions
```

But you also need to pass in the `data` that you pass to the `_source` variable otherwise you're not going to index anything... I suspect that you need to call `get_data_from_file()` for each file in `json_names` and the data you get must be passed into `bulk_json_data`...

Comment: Val thank you for your answer. If I put this in a for loop and use variables for the index name and the source would it work? Because your answer goes for importing multiple records to one index. I need to create multiple indexes and bulk import multiple records to each one of them

Comment: Yes, you can definitely use different index names for each action in the `actions` parameter

Comment: I just wanted to know if you were able to try what I suggested and if it worked out?

Comment: Val thank you for the interest. Unfortunately I cannot grasp it. I cannot grasp the syntax. Practically I have got a loop that goes through a set of excel spreadsheets and each time it iterates it creates a folder where all the tabs from the excel sheet are written as Json files and also create a list with path and filenames. Then another loop should open each one of the json file inside the folder and import it to Elastic. Could you please provide an example on how to do this because I'm out of my depth here? Thank you again fro any help you can provide.

Comment: Maybe you can show the relevant parts of our current python code...

Comment: [link] (https://mega.nz/file/aWI3zIKA#t0FaadaKOEUIMT9rmq-vO7NRPfgt46d4CTKvKlUnYvU)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try it. Last question. Why should I change that line and with what? Thank you for your interest and the time spent to answer my noob questions

Comment: In your code you had `'_type': 'document'` and I changed it to `'_type': '_doc'`